# Find groups with not not a number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I have a dataframe containing some coded answers to a questionnaire.
Each row is a respondent and each column is a question. Not every person responded to the same questions because of some skip logic in the questionnaire therefore I have a sparse dataframe cotaining `NaN`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
prng = np.random.RandomState(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(prng.randint(0,5, size=(10, 3),), columns=['Q1','Q2','Q3'])
# add NaN
df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .3)
print(df)

df

   Q1   Q2   Q3
0  3.0  4.0  2.0
1  4.0  4.0  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  2.0
3  4.0  NaN  2.0
4  4.0  NaN  3.0
5  NaN  3.0  4.0
6  0.0  NaN  NaN
7  4.0  3.0  NaN
8  0.0  NaN  2.0
9  NaN  3.0  3.0
```

The dataframe is quite big around 40K rows and 700 columns... is there an efficient way to find the group(s) of at least n questions that were answered at least by x respondents.

Basic attempt:

```
list_answers = []
for L in range(len(df.columns) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(df.columns, L):
        list_answers.append([subset, df.loc[df[list(subset)].notna().all(axis=1)].index.to_list()])

list_answers[1:]
 [[('Q1',), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]],
 [('Q2',), [0, 1, 5, 7, 9]],
 [('Q3',), [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]],
 [('Q1', 'Q2'), [0, 1, 7]],
 [('Q1', 'Q3'), [0, 2, 3, 4, 8]],
 [('Q2', 'Q3'), [0, 5, 9]],
 [('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'), [0]]]

min_num_questions = 2
min_num_respondents = 3
group_questions = [[i[0], i[1]] for i in list_answers[1:] if len(i[0])>=min_num_questions if len(i[1])>=min_num_respondents]

 group_questions
 [[('Q1', 'Q2'), [0, 6, 9]],
 [('Q1', 'Q3'), [0, 1, 9]],
 [('Q2', 'Q3'), [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9]]]
```

Comment: Finding all the combinations of questions is not the way to go as you have 700 questions and it will have `2^700` combinations. @gabboshow

Comment: I know... that's why o_o... I can maybe have a filter for groups with at least x respondents and/or y questions.. but not sure it will help

Comment: Why do you want a combination of all questions?

Comment: because I have to analyse this questionnaire, but I don't know the skip logic implemented.. the skip logic determines group of people so I want to analyse these people separately. You can also think as a way to create n datasets without NaN

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to keep the information, of which questions were answered by each person, one possible approach is to drop all columns (=questions) first that do not meet the criteria. In a second step you could store the questions that were answered in a separate result column and group it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
prng = np.random.RandomState(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(prng.randint(0,5, size=(10, 3),), columns=['Q1','Q2','Q3'])

# add NaN
df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .3)

###    Q1   Q2   Q3
###0  3.0  4.0  2.0
###1  NaN  4.0  1.0
###2  NaN  2.0  2.0
###3  4.0  NaN  2.0
###4  4.0  1.0  NaN
###5  1.0  3.0  4.0
###6  0.0  3.0  1.0
###7  4.0  3.0  0.0
###8  0.0  NaN  NaN
###9  1.0  3.0  3.0

min_num_questions = 2
min_num_respondents = 3

#drop questions that were NOT answered by at least x persons
dfResult = df.drop(df.columns[df.count(axis=0) < min_num_respondents], axis=1)

###dfResult matches df in this case

#store question names, in case at least x questions were answered
dfResult['ans'] = dfResult.apply(lambda row: tuple(dfResult.columns[row.notnull()].values) if row.count() >= min_num_questions else nan, axis=1)

###    Q1   Q2   Q3           ans
###0  3.0  4.0  2.0  (Q1, Q2, Q3)
###1  NaN  4.0  1.0      (Q2, Q3)
###2  NaN  2.0  2.0      (Q2, Q3)
###3  4.0  NaN  2.0      (Q1, Q3)
###4  4.0  1.0  NaN      (Q1, Q2)
###5  1.0  3.0  4.0  (Q1, Q2, Q3)
###6  0.0  3.0  1.0  (Q1, Q2, Q3)
###7  4.0  3.0  0.0  (Q1, Q2, Q3)
###8  0.0  NaN  NaN           NaN
###9  1.0  3.0  3.0  (Q1, Q2, Q3)

#group by answered questions
dictResult = dfResult.groupby('ans').indices

###{
###('Q1', 'Q2'): array([4], dtype=int64), 
###('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'): array([0, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64), 
###('Q1', 'Q3'): array([3], dtype=int64), 
###('Q2', 'Q3'): array([1, 2], dtype=int64)
###}
```

#### Edit: Include supersets

In order to include supersets, you could step through the resulting dict and append the list with values, where applicable.

```
output = dictResult
for k,v in dictResult.items():
    for subk in dictResult.keys():
        if subk != k and set(subk).issuperset(k):
            output[k] = np.append(output[k], dictResult[subk])

###{
###('Q1', 'Q2'): array([4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64), 
###('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'): array([0, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64), 
###('Q1', 'Q3'): array([3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64), 
###('Q2', 'Q3'): array([1, 2, 0, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64)
###}
```

Comment: great answer, the only thing is that the respondent of ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3') should be added also to the respondents of ('Q1', 'Q2'), ('Q1', 'Q3') and ('Q2', 'Q3'). For example if I would want to select the group of questions with the highest number of respondent, that would be ('Q2', 'Q3') : [0,1,2,5,6,7,9]

Comment: @gabboshow: oh, you are right. I missed that. Kindly have a look at the edit. It is not pretty, but looping through the resulting dict only is a little more efficient in terms of performance